# java compiling with jars

Tags: java, compilation

I'm trying to figure out how an existing Java program (I did not make myself ofcourse) was compiled with existing jars

I have `Test.java` (original source file):

```
package Demo;
//import classes from jars here etc...
public class Test {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  etc...
 }
}
```

Now I have two other jars:

```
file1.jar
file2.jar
Demo.jar
```

There is a batch script to run it:

```
@echo off
set CLASSPATH="file1.jar";"file2.jar";"Demo.jar"
java -cp %CLASSPATH% Demo.Test
```

This WORKS, but now I need to change the source file Test.java, recompile and run with the jars class dependencies. (sorry if I'm not making sense)

---

Now, I have tried to recompile this to reproduce same results with no luck:

```
javac -cp file1.jar;file2.jar;Demo.jar Test.java
```

defined manifest:

```
manifest.mf
Main-class: Demo.Test
```

Created directory "store" for class files and moved class files there

Ran:

```
jar -cmf manifest.mf Demo.jar store
```

Which created the "Demo.jar"

Then I ran the run the batch script above but not the same results (doesn't work at all)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did the batch script not work?

Comment: yes, the batch script works initially. this is an existing program I'm trying to figure out how it works so I can recompile it when I make changes to the "Test.java" and run it the same way

Comment: Can you show the error that occurs? Might point us in the right direction

Comment: Your batch script is for **running** the code. It sets `CLASSPATH` so JVM knows where to look for the required classes.  It has nothing to do with compiling the code.

Comment: when running batch script again: cannot find or load Demo.Test class

Comment: `java` - runs the byte-code
`javac` - complies (translates Java statements to byte-code)
`jar` - builds JAR files (packs compiled classes together)

Comment: hi PM 77-1, I know what its referring too. All I'm asking is general help/pointers on how to recreate the results in this case with jars provided and the source file.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to recreate and from what point?

Comment: Just like how I explained I have a folder with the jar files, a source file that I want to change and recompile and run with the jar files class dependencies, that is all.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to create true executable jars as soon as you rely on external jars.

The only solution here is to :

- put all jars in the same folder : yours and its dependencies
- add a [classpath entry inside your manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)
- launch the jar using `java -jar Demo.jar`

The manifest will have to look like :

```
manifest.mf
Main-class: Demo.Test
Class-Path: file1.jar file2.jar
```

Comment: what I'm just trying to do is because the Test.java file is dependent on the jars classes, I want to make some changes to the Test.java file and make it work. I don't know how to get it to compile and link appropriately. I was hoping for some steps to take to get this done in the original working way that I described.

Comment: Try better and read the docs I mentioned, it's the official java way.